# how to get leetcode graphql schema

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

Leetcode GraphQl Link : https://leetcode.com/graphql

i am requesting for schema using apollo android sendBox :https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer

my query :

```
query getUserProfile($username: String!) {
  matchedUser(username: $username) {
    username
    submitStats: submitStatsGlobal {
      acSubmissionNum {
        difficulty
        count
        submissions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when i entered above url it gives unable to reach server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not safe for a company to expose its graphql schema in production, so Leetcode disabled its introspection feature which will let everybody know all the schema.

See https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/security/why-you-should-disable-graphql-introspection-in-production/

Also, to help you guys I've created a repository that contains as many graphql queries as I could find.

**Please refer https://github.com/akarsh1995/leetcode-graphql-queries**

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the network tab of the browser, I was able to determine a few endpoints :

```
https://leetcode.com/graphql?query=query
{     
      userContestRanking(username:  "YOUR_USERNAME") 
      {
        attendedContestsCount
        rating
        globalRanking
        totalParticipants
        topPercentage    
      }
      userContestRankingHistory(username: "YOUR_USERNAME")
      {
        attended
        trendDirection
        problemsSolved
        totalProblems
        finishTimeInSeconds
        rating
        ranking
        contest 
        {
          title
          startTime
        }
      }
}
```

Sample Responese :

```
  "data": {
    "userContestRanking": {
      "attendedContestsCount": 60,
      "rating": 1745.1129418722594,
      "globalRanking": 32151,
      "totalParticipants": 350123,
      "topPercentage": 9.59
    },
    "userContestRankingHistory": [
      {
        "attended": false,
        "trendDirection": "NONE",
        "problemsSolved": 0,
        "totalProblems": 3,
        "finishTimeInSeconds": 0,
        "rating": 1500.0,
        "ranking": 0,
        "contest": {
          "title": "Weekly Contest 2",
          "startTime": 1472347800
        }
      },
      {
        "attended": false,
        "trendDirection": "NONE",
        "problemsSolved": 0,
        "totalProblems": 4,
        "finishTimeInSeconds": 0,
        "rating": 1500.0,
        "ranking": 0,
        "contest": {
          "title": "Weekly Contest 3",
          "startTime": 1472990400
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
?query=query 
{ 
    matchedUser(username: "user4029ok") 
    {
        username
        submitStats: submitStatsGlobal 
        {
            acSubmissionNum 
            {
                difficulty
                count
                submissions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//TRY this after leetcode.com/graphql/

Comment: how to send req through post man?